# Finding the Last Value in a Dynamic Row (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I'm attempting to find the last available row in a dynamic row in another worksheet, and am having difficulties getting the formula working.

I'm was using the ol' faithful 99^99 lookup to find the value,

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,'Import'!4:4)
```

And it worked well while the data in the Calculations sheet matched up with the Import sheet. However (for example) row 48 in the Calculations sheet might correspond with row 51 in the Import sheet, whilst row 49 in Calculations would match with row 68.

In the above instance I want to replace the "4:4" with a dynamic reference to another row based on a lookup.

My best attempt so far is:

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,INDIRECT(“'Import'!”&MATCH($A4,'Import'!$A:$A,0)&”:”&MATCH($A4,'Import'!$A:$A,0)))
```

Or in psuedo:

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,("'Import'!" & R & ":" & R))
Where R = Row in another sheet, corresponding to the value in column A of the current sheet.
```

But it's not giving me working results. I've tried a handful of variations with MIN, ROWS, LOOKUP, etc.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your sheets? It will help to work on your issue

Answer (score 0):

I would use INDEX/MATCH where possible so it would look something like this

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,INDEX(Import!$A$1:$AA$100,MATCH(A1,Import!$A$1:$A$100,0),0))
```

adjusting ranges as required.